# Center horizontal line across div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to centre a horizontal line across a div which can change dynamically depending on the content inside it. I have created a div with content inside it.

[image]

The horizontal line should be centred across either side of the box but should not be visible inside the div.

[image]

html

```
<div class ="box">
<hr/>
<div class="container">
          <h3>Click on either of the two buttons!</h3>
          <button class="button ">Button 1</button>
          <button class="button ">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
hr {
    border: 2px solid;
}
.container {
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 45%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 10px 10px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's the link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/nabeela/pen/pBBZVX)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Introduce a little bit of Flexbox CSS. Hope this helps with what you need.

This is putting three elements into one `<div>` and then aligning them left to right on the same row.

("Run Code Snippet" and click full page size, you shall see the design as requested in the image in the question).

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}

hr {
  align-self: center;
  background: black;
  width: 40%; 
  height: 1px
}
.container {
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 10px 10px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class ="box">
    <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <h3>Click on either of the two buttons!</h3>
                <button class="button ">Button 1</button>
                <button class="button ">Button 2</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use `transform` to do what you are after.

Here I have added a fixed height to your parent container and then vertically centred both the hr and the box using

```
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
```

All this does is position the element vertically center using the parent elements height.

```css
hr {
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  border: 2px solid;  
}
.box{
  height:300px;
}
.container {
   position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-55%);
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 45%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:white;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 10px 10px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<hr/>
<div class="container">
          <h3>Click on either of the two buttons!</h3>
          <button class="button ">Button 1</button>
          <button class="button ">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeeJNq)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.example {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.example::before,
.example::after {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  content: '';
  align-self: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
}

 .example::before {
   margin-left: -100%;
}

.example::after {
  margin-right: -100%;
}

.example div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <h3>Click on either of the two buttons!</h3>
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>  
  </div>
</div>
```